# A Single Column over Multiple Rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

Is it possible to achieve this?

[image]

By slightly modifying this codes?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

**EDITED**
I can achieve this using below. I'm wondering if there's any other simple way.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post *all* of the relevant code?

Comment: @Zim That's the code that I have. Two sets of it for 2 rows (left image)

Comment: What about your CSS code? After all, Bootstrap and Grid are both coded in CSS...If you show us how you wrote the CSS, we can tell you why your column isn't spanning both rows.

Answer (score 0):

tarako 
You may try it by

just add a single `div` in start and add its `height` plus hide the lower `div`

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="height:10px(according to you)" class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi you can try with this code**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reports</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <main class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">
          <h1>Dashboard</h1>

          <section class="row text-center placeholders">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAJ12AAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <div class="text-muted">Something else</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAADcgwAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAAJ12AAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAADcgwAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" width="200" height="200" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
          </section>
            </div>
          </div>
```